# vertical align for image inside ul li

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble making my images inside my ul li align vertically. Seems like the `display table and vertical align` doesn't work for me. is there any other solution for that?

[here](http://prntscr.com/8rt5z1) what it looks like.
this is the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0k72h4w5/)

fiddle is not working 100% but you can take a look at what the structure is...

the very basic thing that I can do is set a max-height and auto the width. so that every image is the same

Comment: you want the images to be displayed vertically as list or horizontally??? if you want to display it vertically remove `float:left` property

Comment: No. the slider is good horizontal i just want the image to be align vertically like using the 'vertical align middle'

Comment: sorry mate you have make the demo good enough to see the fault in it.. because as far as i can see all the images are in same alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No comments, just try.

[More info about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x140/000/fff">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x190/000/fff">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/000/fff">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css absolute layout:

1. Make `ul li` element `position:relative`
2. Add the css properties to `ul li img`

   ```
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   ```
3. Give any size property to the `li` and `li img` as you want

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
ul li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
 
}
ul li:nth-child(1) img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### See also:

- [How To Center Anything With CSS](https://codemyviews.com/blog/how-to-center-anything-with-css)